# How to resolve graphql "failed to recognize JSON request: 'EOF' " error

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to use a Rest API, but when I query, I receive the following error that I don't understand, I've tried to look at similar questions here but they are very particular cases. This is the code I use

```
payload = {"query":"{
  viewer {
    zones(filter: { zoneTag: " + zoneTag + " }) {
      httpRequests1dGroups(
        orderBy: [date_ASC]
        limit: 1000
        filter: { date_gt: \"2019-07-15\" }
      ) {
        date: dimensions {
          date
        }
        sum {
          cachedBytes
          bytes
        }
      }
    }
  }
}","variables":{}}
```

it is giving me error like this

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "failed to recognize JSON request: 'EOF'",
            "path": null,
            "extensions": {
                "timestamp": "2021-04-21T13:17:21.939789333Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However this is my curl command

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-Auth-Email: CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL" \
  -H "X-Auth-key: CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY" \
  --data "$(echo $payload)" \
  https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a query which isn't parsed as a JSON.

You need to parse the body of the query before you send it forward as a payload

```
payload = JSON.parse(event.body);
```

Or you can escape double quotes in your query (notice you have missing escapes)

```
let query = '{\"query\":\"{
  viewer {
    zones(filter: { zoneTag: \" + zoneTag + \" }) {
      httpRequests1dGroups(
        orderBy: [date_ASC]
        limit: 1000
        filter: { date_gt: \"2019-07-15\" }
      ) {
        date: dimensions {
          date
        }
        sum {
          cachedBytes
          bytes
        }
      }
    }
  }
}\",\"variables\":{}}'
```

Comment: thankyou for answering firstly,but none of the method is working for me. Can you check again i have done a small editing

Comment: @Tomar - I am writing .sh script so while adding this "payload = JSON.parse(event.body);" and running its showing me syntax error and escaping the double quotes too dint worked for me